# get array value by index jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, indexing

I have an javascript array that has the following values,

```
let arr = ["2","3","4","5","6"];
```

I have a second array that has three integers,

```
let index = [1,3,4];
```

How would I use JQuery (or Javascript) to use the array to get the index from arr, and add it to a new array. I want to add these strings to a new array.

```
indexArr = ["3","5","6"]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a loop. Personally I prefer this method over `map` because I find this easier to understand, but it's personal preference.

```js
let arr = ["2","3","4","5","6"];
let index = [1,3,4];
let indexArr = [];
for(var i=0; i<index.length; i++) {
    indexArr.push(arr[index[i]]);
}
console.log(indexArr);
```

Comment: @dark_dab0 Great, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

Simple, just use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
let arr = ["2","3","4","5","6"];
let index = [1,3,4];

let indexArr = index.map(i => arr[i]);

console.log(indexArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with simple .map

```
let arr = ["2","3","4","5","6"];
let index = [1,3,4];
index.map(x=>arr[x]) //["3", "5", "6"]
```